# Store and return a previous value for same variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to store a previous value for a variable, whose variable was already changed through a dialog, and then convert that variable's value back to the previously set value if the dialog is cancelled and returns `None`. For instance, consider:

letter_height = 30
letter_width = 50

I would like the user to change the value through this, which does work:

```
def NewLetterDimensions():
    global letter_height
    letter_height = (numinput("New Letter Height", "Please set the new letter height: ", minval = 10, maxval = 170))
    if letter_height == None:
        listen()

    global letter_width
    letter_width = (numinput("New Letter Width", "Please set the new    letter width: ", minval = 10, maxval = 170))
    if letter_width == None:
        listen()
```

Which is called by this:

```
onkey(NewLetterDimensions, "k")
```

But, if the dialog is cancelled, I want the "if" statement to be able to return the stored previous value, so that the variable is changed to the previous value instead of `None`. So, how would I go about being able to implement this? So, I want this:

```
def NewLetterDimensions():
    global letter_height
    letter_height = (numinput("New Letter Height", "Please set the new letter height: ", minval = 10, maxval = 170))
    if letter_height == None:
        [] <- # Return previously set letter height (whether from previous dialog or not)
        listen()

global letter_width
letter_width = (numinput("New Letter Width", "Please set the new    letter width: ", minval = 10, maxval = 170))
if letter_width == None:
    [] <- # Return previously set letter width (whether from previous dialog or not)
    listen()
```

And yes, this is in turtle graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
user_input = (numinput("New Letter Height", "Please set the new letter height: ",
                             minval=10, maxval=170))
letter_height = letter_height if user_input is None else user_input
```

This changes `letter_height` to `user_input` only if it is not `None` and keeps the old value otherwise.

BTW, always compare `None`with `is` test as [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests:

> Comparisons to singletons like `None` should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators.